# Changing Axis Type in Charts.js Convert Labels to Scientific Notation

Tags: javascript

I am using following code to plot a graph in which x-axis is logarithmic but labels on the x-axis are being displayed in scientific notation. I want them to appear like the numbers used in the data. I have tried using `callback: function (value, index, values)` but plot disappear after using these. Can somebody help me that what should I change to get this right.

PS. I cannot use charts.js above version 2.9.4 due to some limitations.

Best Regards.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- saved from url=(0014)about:internet -->
<html>
<head>
    <title>Chart</title>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=Edge'>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-colorschemes"></script>
    <style>
        body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
        #container { width: 100%; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id='container'>
    <canvas id='myChart'></canvas>
</div>
<script>
    Chart.defaults.global.animation.duration = 1000;
    Chart.defaults.global.animation.easing = 'linear';
    var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels: ['10','2000','30000','50000','60000','700000',],
            datasets: [
               {label: 'ABC' ,
                fill: true ,
                data: [ 
                  { x: '10', y: 2 },
                  { x: '2000', y: 4 },
                  { x: '30000', y: 7 },
                  { x: '50000', y: 8 },
                  { x: '60000', y: 8.5 },
                  { x: '700000', y: 9 }
                  ],
                borderWidth: 1},
             ]
        },
        options: {
            aspectRatio:  1.6,
            title: {
                display: true,
                position: 'top',
                text: 'Ref Data'
            },
            legend: {
                display: true,
                position: 'right',
            },
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    id: 'first-y-Axis',
                    display: true,
                    scaleLabel: {
                       display: true,
                       labelString: 'Demo y-axis'
                    }
                    }],
                xAxes: [{
                    id: 'first-x-Axis',
                    display: true,
                    type: 'logarithmic',
                    scaleLabel: {
                       display: true,
                       labelString: 'Demo x-axis'
                    },
                    ticks: {
                       min:  0 ,
                       max:  700000 
                       //Following commented line were copied from internet for the solution but chart is shown blank after uncommenting these
                       //callback: function (value, index, values) {
                       //return Number(value.toString()) //pass tick values as a string into Number function
                       //}
                    }
                    }]
            },
            plugins: {
                colorschemes: {
                    scheme: 'brewer.Paired12'
                    }
                }
        }
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The callback just works fine **with** or **without** `toString()`

```
callback: function (val, index, ticks) {
   return Number(val);
}
```

**And** in `version 2.9.4`, you should use `suggestedMin` and `suggestedMax` **instead of** `min` and `max`.

https://www.chartjs.org/docs/2.9.4/axes/cartesian/linear.html

If you want to limit the number of **ticks** for the clear view, You can set the `maxTicksLimit` property.

**Snippet**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- saved from url=(0014)about:internet -->
<html>
<head>
    <title>Chart</title>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=Edge'>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-colorschemes"></script>
    <style>
        body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
        #container { width: 100%; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id='container'>
    <canvas id='myChart'></canvas>
</div>
<script>
    Chart.defaults.global.animation.duration = 1000;
    Chart.defaults.global.animation.easing = 'linear';
    var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels: ['10','2000','30000','50000','60000','700000',],
            datasets: [
               {label: 'ABC' ,
                fill: true ,
                data: [ 
                  { x: '10', y: 2 },
                  { x: '2000', y: 4 },
                  { x: '30000', y: 7 },
                  { x: '50000', y: 8 },
                  { x: '60000', y: 8.5 },
                  { x: '700000', y: 9 }
                  ],
                borderWidth: 1},
             ]
        },
        options: {
            aspectRatio:  1.6,
            title: {
                display: true,
                position: 'top',
                text: 'Ref Data'
            },
            legend: {
                display: true,
                position: 'right',
            },
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    id: 'first-y-Axis',
                    display: true,
                    scaleLabel: {
                       display: true,
                       labelString: 'Demo y-axis'
                    }
                    }],
                xAxes: [{
                    id: 'first-x-Axis',
                    display: true,
                    type: 'logarithmic',
                    scaleLabel: {
                       display: true,
                       labelString: 'Demo x-axis'
                    },
                    ticks: {
                       maxTicksLimit: 6,
                       suggestedMin: 0,
                       suggestedMax: 700000,
                       callback: function (val, index, ticks) {
                          return Number(val);
                      }
                    }
                    }]
            },
            plugins: {
                colorschemes: {
                    scheme: 'brewer.Paired12'
                    }
                }
        }
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. Axis are marked in normal values but why are min and max not applied correctly. As you can see, min is 0 while max is 70000 and axis level for max are not displayed properly. How can I force that?

Comment: It is a version issue, In 2.9.4 there is no `min` or `max` option. You have to use `suggestedMin` and `suggestedMax` instead. I updated my answer.

Comment: Whenever you refer to the documentation. Make sure you refer to the correct `version`. By default, the doc always lands us on the latest version. :p

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have one another question. How can I show specific x-axis ticks labels. I mean I want to show only 10, 100, 1000, 10000 instead of 10, 70, 400, 1000.... This makes it much crowded. To make it less crowded, I want to show only labels that are 10^n where n=0,1,2,3.... How can I do so?

Comment: @Pacman As I know you cannot specify like `10, 100...` but you **can** limit the `ticks` using `maxTicksLimit`. By setting it will create no more than a specified amount of ticks. The default is 11. Check my answer, I updated it with `maxTicksLimit: 6`

Comment: I found out that by modifying the callback function and adding this conditional return statement, it return only power of 10 values. `if( val==10 || val==100 || val==1000 || val==10000 || val==100000  || val==1000000){`. Can you please add this statement before `return Number(val);` statement into your answer so that it could help someone else too.

Comment: I didn't know that I could edit your answer too. I added the piece of statement into your answer. Know it os showing power of 10 ticks labels but still it misses the last label which should be next power of 10 after the maximum value in the data

Comment: It is not a optimal way, Lemme add an optimal way to do it

Comment: It is not recommended to hardcode all possible values. To check whether the tick is a power of 10 or not, You can do `if (Math.log10(tick) % 1 === 0) { return tick; }`

Comment: Can you update your answer please because I couldn't make it work till now.

Comment: by the way your solution only shows `10`, `10000`, `100000` in chart

Comment: Yes, I knew it wasn't complete yet. I got a little closer to what was required. `if (Math.log10(tick) % 1 === 0) { return tick; }` didn't work however when I used `val` instead of `tick`, it worked but still it has issue that when highest vale is 2000 it only show ticks upto 1000 whereas it should show 10000.

Comment: I today checked it the code in my actual project and found that Math.log10 is not available for IE11 (which is the sole browser my app is using). Is there any other way or have to hard code value. I tried `Math.log(val)/Math.LN10` and `Math.log(val)/Math.log(10)` but few power of 10 ticks values get missing.